# std::ifstream read into vector results in 0 sized vector

Tags: c++

I'm aware that there are other ways to accomplish the read of data. But I am confused, why in this code does the size print as 0? `file.txt` is a random text file with more than 4 characters.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::ifstream ifs("file.txt");
  std::vector<char> file_vec{};
  file_vec.reserve(4);
  ifs.read(file_vec.data(), 4);
  std::cout << file_vec.size() << std::endl;
  ifs.close();
}
```

Comment: `ifs.read` does not change the `size` of the vector, because it has no way of doing that when all you pass is a pointer to the underlying data

Comment: Replace `file_vec.reserve(4);` with `file_vec.resize(4);`

Comment: `reserve` allocates storage for `vector`,  it sets the `vector`s capacity, but doesn't tell `vector` to use it yet, it doesn't set the size. You want to look at `resize`.

Comment: `reserve` does not do what you think it does.

Comment: Better to utilize those other methods.

Comment: The comments already address the underlying issue, I'd also encourage you to [take a look at `std::istream_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator)